# How to display a 2-D array as an html table for a Google Web App Page (using GAS)

Tags: html, arrays, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

Using a code.gs file, I have retrieved data from a Google Spreadsheet and put it into a 2-D array, and then manipulated the array a little bit (with things like transpose, condensing it, etc.).

I am trying to find out how to create a web app / web page that will display this 2-D array as an html table (subject to also being able to set table specifications, like width, color, etc.).

Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will tell you how to do it, generally speaking. Just to display the HTML.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

To choose specific data, you will want to use the .gs file to grab the spread sheet as you have already done. Now, when you're done modifying your array, store it in Properties Service, or Cache Service.

In your HTML page, write a JS function that calls back to the .gs file.

```
google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandeler( function(array) { ... //We'll get to this in a moment... }) 
.getMyArray();
```

In your .gs file, write a function 'getMyArray'. Make it retrieve the array from Property or Cache Service and make it return the array.

Now, it the Success Handeler, use your array, and make it a table.

```
        // 'array' here will be the return of .getMyArray()
  .withSuccessHandler( function(array) {
    for (var i in array) {
      // Here, make every object into a string of the table you want
      // i.e. "<table><td>" + array[i] + "<td> ..."
      // Insert that string into some div.innerHTML
     }
.getMyArray();
```

Easy as pi